# Cannot select value from the suggestion provided while sending text into search box

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

When I enter the text into the text box and use tab out it gets confused with multiple suggestions with almost same name so it give me error.

```java
public class HotelBooking {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\geckodriver-v0.17.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.goibibo.com/");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='header']/div[1]/ul/li[2]/a")).click();
        WebElement EnterCity = driver.findElement(By.id("gosuggest_inputL"));
        EnterCity.click();
        EnterCity.sendKeys("Baroda");
        EnterCity.sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN);
        EnterCity.sendKeys(Keys.TAB);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='Home']/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[3]/div/button")).click();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the value that you want to select, you could do something like this:

```
public class HotelBooking {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\geckodriver-v0.17.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.goibibo.com/");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='header']/div[1]/ul/li[2]/a")).click();
        WebElement EnterCity = driver.findElement(By.id("gosuggest_inputL"));
        EnterCity.click();
        EnterCity.sendKeys("Baroda");
        while (true) {
            EnterCity.sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN);
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            String value = EnterCity.getAttribute("value");
            System.out.println(value);
            if (value.equalsIgnoreCase("Grand Paradise, Vadodara")) {
                EnterCity.click();
                break;
            }
        }}}
```

Comment: I applied but the for .getAttribute("Baroda"); it gives me null exception

Comment: Why do you try ".getAttribute("Baroda");"? From the inspector of the Browser, the info that you need is in the "value" attribute of this "WebElement". So the EnterCity.getAttribute("value"); will return, whenever you do a Keys.ARROW_DOWN, the next value.

Answer (score 0):

When I write code for something like this, I put the code that is going to be reused regularly into functions. I wrote a couple functions, one to get all the suggestions and one to select a suggestion based on an index.

```
public static List<String> getSuggestions(String name)
{
    driver.findElement(By.id("gosuggest_inputL")).sendKeys(name);
    List<WebElement> suggestions = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
            .until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.cssSelector("#react-autosuggest-1 div.mainTxt > span")));
    List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (WebElement suggestion : suggestions)
    {
        names.add(suggestion.getText());
    }

    return names;
}

public static void selectSuggestion(String name, int index)
{
    driver.findElement(By.id("gosuggest_inputL")).sendKeys(name);
    List<WebElement> suggestions = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
            .until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.cssSelector("#react-autosuggest-1 div.mainTxt > span")));
    suggestions.get(index).click();
}
```

You can use it like

```
driver.get("https://www.goibibo.com/");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='header']/div[1]/ul/li[2]/a")).click();
System.out.println(getSuggestions("Baroda"));
selectSuggestion("Baroda", 0);
```

`getSuggestions("Baroda")` contains

```
Ahmedabad
Vadodara (Baroda)
Gandhinagar
Sayaji Gunj, Vadodara
Alkapuri, Vadodara
Vadodara Airport ( BDQ ), Vadodara
MS University of Baroda, Vadodara
Sri Aurobindo Niwas, Vadodara
The Baroda Residency, Vadodara
Grand Paradise, Vadodara
```

and `selectSuggestion("Baroda", 0)` selects `Ahmedabad`

Comment: i used this function but it shows me an error for 'driver'.

Comment: every things looks good by the only thing that bothers me is the "driver'' error "driver can not be resolved.

Comment: You still need the first two lines of your `main()` method. You kept those, right? Otherwise `driver` is not defined.